# Is there a way to make is_search() always return false

Tags: plugin-development

I am making a plugin that display related posts when users put the wrong URL...

Samples are like this

http://diskonblog.net/gandaria/hellow

I do not want to change the theme at all. However, for the sake of coding, I changed the theme to show that is_search() shows 1.

What should I do so that when the themes execute is_search(), it shows false instead

I tried

```
function returnfalse( ){
    return false;
}
add_filter ('is_search','returnfalse');
```

and that didn't work.

The code in the plugin are these:

```
class RandomPosts {
    function orderby($orderby) {
    if ( get_query_var('random') == 'true' )
    return "RAND()";
    else
    return $orderby;
    }

    function register_query_var($vars) {
        $vars[] = 'random';
        return $vars;
    }
}
add_filter( 'posts_orderby', array('RandomPosts', 'orderby') );
add_filter( 'query_vars', array('RandomPosts', 'register_query_var') );

function query_random_posts($query) {

    return query_posts($query . '&random=true');
}
```

To examine what's wrong, I simplify the code

```
function setUp404Template($toInclude = "default")
{

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

    //queryBasedOnPage ();
    query_posts('&random=true');
    if ($toInclude=="default")
    {
        $toInclude= get_template_directory() . "/index.php"; //Can also require(TEMPLATEPATH . "/search.php"); if exist
    }
    require($toInclude); 


}

function redirect_404() {
    global $options, $wp_query;
    if ($wp_query->is_404) {
     setUp404Template();
       // $redirect_404_url = esc_url(get_permalink(get_page_by_title($page_title))); 
       // wp_redirect( $redirect_404_url );

        exit();


    }
}
```

Everything works as intended.

However, if I change        `query_posts('&random=true');` to

```
query_posts('s=makan ikan&random=true');
```

the is_search() flag is turned on.

Basically I want to be able to return posts that's actually relevant and then keep is_search () to false.

Comment: The problem you're trying to solve, is that how to display google ads in each excerpt on search pages ?

Comment: Well it could be another solution for my problem. However, for this one, I want to display some random posts and then optimize for certain keywords while keeping is_search() false

Comment: `query_posts` breaks the main query, so even if you set `is_search()` to false, `query_posts` will most probably break it and reset it to true. This is one of the very big reasons why you should never ever use `query_posts`

Comment: So what should I do instead? How do I set it to false after running query_posts? What should I run instead

Answer (score 0):

To is_search() allways return false you can use:

```
add_action( 'parse_query', 'search_even_empty' );
function search_even_empty($query)
{
    $query->is_search = false;    
}
```